# How to put a frame around the footer section, with text sitting at the bottom center?

Tags: context

I'm trying to put draw lines around the footer area and put some text at the center bottom of the area. I've been trying variations of the below for a while now:

```
\showframe

\defineframed[FooterSection]
    [
        width=\makeupwidth,
        height=broad,
        location=bottom,
        frame=on,
        rulethickness=3pt
    ]

\setupfootertexts[\FooterSection{Some text}]

\starttext
    Hello.
\stoptext
```

This gives me the following:

[image]

I haven't found some combination of `height` and `location` or other parameters I've discovered to give me the desired effect. As it is, the box is too short, but the text is in the right place. How do I extend the height so it goes to the top of the footer area?

Comment: You can use `height=\footerheight` to make the box as high as the footer. If the contents don't change you can use `boffset` to move it downwards (this is not automic, though), e.g.`boffset=-0.5\footerheight` gives good results in your MWE. (I don't really know ConTeXt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the full footer, but re-align the content.

```
\showframe

\defineframed[FooterSection]
    [width=max,
     height=max,
     location=bottom,
     align={low,middle},
     frame=on,
     rulethickness=3pt]

\setupfootertexts[\FooterSection{Some text}]

\starttext
    Hello.
\stoptext
```

Comment: `width=max` and `height=max` is more expressive and you are missing a comma after `rulethickness=3pt` (in this case it does not matter but most of the time it does).

Comment: @HenriMenke I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Just enable the frame around the footer using `\setupbackgrounds`.  This does not require to specify the alignment manually, doesn't screw with the existing baseline, and does not require you to wrap the footer content into a macro.

```
\setupbackgrounds
  [footer]
  [text]
  [frame=on]

\setupfootertexts[Some text]

\starttext

Hello World!

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `max` value for the `width` and `height` keys to use the available space for the frame. Another setting you have to do is to disable the `strut` for the footer setup, otherwise the frame won’t fill the complete vertical area of the footer.

```
\showframe

\startsetups [footer]
  \startframed [width=max,height=max,align={middle,low},rulethickness=3pt]
    Some text
  \stopframed
\stopsetups

\setupfooter [strut=no]

\setupfootertexts[\texsetup{footer}]

\starttext
Hello.
\stoptext
```